# Function in a Constructor in PHP white page dont see anything

Tags: php, html

Im Using PhP 7.2.2 and Apache/2.4.29 (Win32)
Sorry for my english, is a little bad.

I wanna register some variables on my table, and i dont know why dont work, i wanna register a name called "nombre", a Code called "codigo" that is necesary generate randomly, a Date Expedition called "fecha_exp", a Date of expiration called "fecha_ven" and the unity of the variable called "unidad". But when i try register with the function "registrar" doesnt work, just only see a white page without anything.
This is my HTML5 called "medicamentos.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../../index.php"> Volver </a> <br>
<a href="../../Controladores/ControladorMedicamentos.php?operacion=index"> Listar Medicamentos</a>
<h1>Registro de Medicamentos</h1>
<form action="../../Controladores/ControladorMedicamentos.php" method="POST" name="form"> 
<p> Ingrese el nombre del producto </p> <input name="nombre" type="text"> <br>
<p> Ingrese la fecha de Expedicion del medicamento</p> <input type="date" name="fecha_exp"><br>
<p> Ingrese la fecha de Vencimiento del medicamento</p> <input type="date" name="fecha_ven"> <br>
<p> Seleccione la Unidad</p>
<select name="unidad" title="Seleccione la unidad">
<option value="ml>"> ml</option>
<option value="cc>"> cc</option>
<option value="mg>"> mg</option>
<option value="grs>"> grs</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="operacion" value="guardar">
<input type="submit" name="guardar" value="guardar">
<input type="reset" name="limpiar" value="limpiar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Im have this code:

```
public function registrar(){
        header("location: ../Vistas/Medicamentos/medicamentos.php");
}
public function guardar(){
    extract($_POST);
    $db=new clasedb();
    $conex=$db->conectar();
            $caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!*$%#/.-,"; 
            $numerodeletras=5; 
            $codigo = ""; 
            $i=0;
            for($i=0;$i<$numerodeletras;$i++)
            {
            $codigo .= substr($caracteres,rand(0,strlen($caracteres)),1);
        }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM medicamentos WHERE codigo='".$codigo."'"; 
    $res=mysqli_query($conex,$sql);
    $cuantos=mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if ($cuantos>0){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("CODIGO YA EXISTE");
            window.location="ControladorMedicamentos.php?operacion=registrar";
        </script>
            <?php
        } else {
            $sql="INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (null,'".$nombre."','".$codigo."','".$fecha_exp."','".$fecha_ven."','".$unidad."')";
            $result=mysqli_query($conex,$sql);
            if ($result) {
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        if (confirm("REGISTRO EXITOSO, DESEA INGRSAR OTRO?")){
                            window.location="ControladorMedicamentos.php?operacion=registrar";
                        } else{
                            window.location="ControladorMedicamentos.php?operacion=index";
                        }
                    </script>
                <?php

                }
            }       
        }
```

with this constructor:

```
static function controlador($operacion) {
    $medicamento=new ControladorMedicamentos(); // Creando objeto de la case
    switch ($operacion) {
        case 'index':
            $medicamento->index();
            break;
        case 'registrar':
            $medicamento->registrar();
            break; 
        case 'guardar':
            $medicamento->guardar();
            break; 
        case 'modificar':
            $medicamento->modificar();
            break;
        case 'actualizar':
            $medicamento->actualizar();
            break;  
        case 'eliminar':
            $medicamento->eliminar();
            break;
        default:
            ?>  <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("No existe la ruta");
                window.location="ControladorMedicamentos.php?operacion=index";
            </script>
            <?php
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In your constructor it looks like you have one too many closing curly braces `}`.

Comment: Because are in one class global like this:
    class ControladorMedicamentos{
    static function controlador($operacion) { 
    }    }

Comment: FINISHED MY PROBLEM, is the syntax "SQL" my table isn't "usuarios" is "medicamentos" Ty!